# mysql won't be installed on ubuntu

Tags: command-line, apache2, mysql

i tried to install apache on ubuntu, and worked,

i tried to install php5 on ubuntu, and thats worked too.

but if im installed mysql, it wont be installed, i didnt know whats going on, i'm new to ubuntu

here's my terminal code

```
 sudo apt-get -f install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

and after i submit that code, it appear like :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-auth-mysql : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.13-1) but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
 perl : Depends: perl-modules (>= 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.4) but 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.3 is to be installed
 php5-mysql : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.13-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

so how to fix this issue?
thanks a lot

Comment: run only `sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such occations like this, you need to put the packages "is not going to be installed " in to the main installing list.

Use the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql libmysqlclient18 mysql-server-5.5 perl-modules
```